# docker-compose.yml for spring boot application using postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I develop a spring boot aplication and I have a docker-compose.yml file like that:

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - db:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5332:5432"
    networks:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db:
```

When I try to run this command:
`docker-compose config`
it gives the error:
`ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option for networks: 'db' Unsupported config option for services: 'db' Unsupported config option for volumes: 'db'`
What might be the reason?

I am a newbie with docker so I have no idea what i am doing.

Comment: Do you know which version of the Compose tool you're using?  Does adding a line `version: '3.8'` at the top of the file help?  (There are two versions of the Compose tool, and they interpret files without `version:` very differently.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the dash inside `networks:` when referring to network `db`. Also add a colon:

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - db:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5332:5432"
    networks:
      db:
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db:
```